# Is $C_0^\infty $ dense in $W^{m,p}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Is $C_0^\infty $ dense in $W^{m,p}$?

Here $C_0^\infty$ = $C_c ^ \infty$ : $C^\infty$ with compact supports, and $W^{m,p}$ : Sobolev spaces.

Comment: yes it is indeed .

Comment: @Ananda Thank you Ananda, is the proof of this statement difficult?

Comment: You can find the proof of it in Evans PDE. It's not that difficult although i found it difficult when i saw it first .

Comment: You mean $C_0^{\infty}(\Bbb R^d)$, or of a particular open set?

Comment: Davide makes a good point: the density depends on the domain, as well as on the exponents $m, p$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo How about the situation $C_0^\infty (\mathbb R^d )$ with $ W^{1,2}$ ?

Comment: It works even for $p\in [1,+\infty)$, the proof is standard, first reducing to the case $u$ with a bounded singular support, then taking the convolution with a mollifier.

Comment: I guess so.....

Comment: @HighGPA Your name is funny haha

Comment: @KitWong My name used to be LowGPA, but someone suggested me to change it...